# How should I write SQLite queries?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

When writing queries to Database in SQLite should I write them like this:

```
String query = "SELECT Items.ItemName, Items.ItemId, Items.Checked FROM Lists JOIN Items ON Lists.Id = Items.IdList WHERE Lists.Name=?";
```

or like this:

```
String query = "SELECT " + TABLE_ITEMS + "." + ITEM_NAME + ", " + TABLE_ITEMS + "." + ITEM_ID + ", " + TABLE_ITEMS
                + "." + ITEM_CHECKED + " FROM " + TABLE_LISTS + " JOIN " + TABLE_ITEMS + " ON " + TABLE_LISTS
                + "." + LIST_ID + "=" + TABLE_ITEMS + "." + ITEM_ID_LIST_FOREIGN_KEY + " WHERE " + TABLE_LISTS + "." + LIST_NAME + "=?";
```

Are there any principles on what should I use?

Comment: The first method is **faster**. Because concatenating strings is stressful for the compiler. Which is why you typically use a StringBuilder to concatenate strings. Other than this, both methods produce the very same query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the first option. Yes, if you want to change a field/table name, you'll have a lot of replacing, but...

If you decide to write raw queries instead of using ORM, then replacing is always inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is what I usually prefer. This is because :

- If you want to change one of the fields of the table, you wouldn't require updating every query. Just update the fields once and all the queries will work fine.
- When changing the Database version. You can easily update that in the second method.

There are no 'principles', but using the second method has a clear advantage over the first one.